# Find nearest neighbors for arrays of different dimentions

Tags: python, arrays, nearest-neighbor

I have to compute a similarity measure on several thousands of uneven arrays. 
The naive implementation is basically in O(n²) and it's taking too long for the number of arrays I have.
Hopefully, I'm interested only in the similarity for the most similar arrays. 
So far I used the sci-kit learn implementation of `NearestNeighbors` which does the job for arrays with the same number of dimensions. However, `NearestNeighbors` is based on a KD-tree and I think it's not possible to apply this algorithm for uneven arrays.

Is there any alternative for arrays of different dimensions?

Here is a code snippet summarizing the problem:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neighbors.unsupervised import NearestNeighbors


def partial_mse(a: np.array, b: np.array) -> float:
    def mse(a: np.array, b: np.array) -> float:
        mse = (np.square(a - b)).mean()
        return -np.sqrt(mse)

    if a.size == b.size:
        return mse(a, b)

    # a is always the bigger one
    if a.size < b.size:
        a, b = b, a

    partial_mse = [mse(a[i:i + b.size], b) for i in range(a.size - b.size + 1)]
    return np.max(partial_mse)

uneven_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [3, 2, 6], [2, 1, 3], [3]])
even_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3,2, 4, 1], [3, 2, 6, 1], [2, 6, 1, 3], [3, 5, 2, 0]])


nnfit = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='auto', n_jobs=-1,
                         metric=partial_mse, metric_params={}).fit(uneven_array)
```

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries I found that:

Filling the space with a default value is the only way to use `NearestNeighbors` and KD-tree.
However, the default value is contaminating the similarity function. The most similar part of the features will be the part with the same filling value.

I fixed it by adding the filling value as parameter of `partial_mse` and filtering out this value inside `partial_mse`. This filling value should be a value that doesn't exist on the arrays, otherwise, it will filter out true values !

```
def partial_mse(a: np.array, b: np.array, **kwargs) -> float:
    [...]
    fill_value = kwargs["fill_value"]
    a, b = a[a != fill_value], b[b != fill_value]
    [...]

nnfit = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10, algorithm='auto', n_jobs=-1, \
 metric=partial_mse, metric_params={"fill_value": fill_value).fit(matrix_features)
```

Answer (score 1):

NearestNeighbour algorithms are based on abstracting the arrays as a n-dimensional point. So, having points of different dimensions are going to throw the algorithm out of whack, and possibly won't give you what you were looking for even if you managed to implement it.

if n is the maximum number of dimension, then each lower dimension (k) point actually corresponds to (n-k+1) possible points in the higher dimension space (by filling the missing dimensions with the elements of array a), and the metric you chose would return the maximum similarity out of the (n-k+1) points.

Comment: I was thinking of this method. However, my arrays already have a lot of 0. If I use 0 as a filling number, it can modify the similarity measure. 
Maybe using a very huge number like `np.inf` could do the trick

Comment: Actually, NearestNeighbors throw me an error for using np.inf